# Chrome runs tests twice in karma

Tags: google-chrome, karma-runner

When using Chrome in my karma tests, I often (more than 50% of all runs) see that each test is executed twice by Chrome. Below you can find an example output and my configuration.

How can I stop this? What is the cause?

```
karma start --single-run --browsers Firefox,Chrome

INFO [karma]: Karma v0.12.17 server started at http://localhost:9876/
INFO [launcher]: Starting browser Firefox
INFO [launcher]: Starting browser Chrome

INFO [Chrome 36.0.1985 (Linux)]: Connected on socket RV8G8p63bCLQGaAJW9Hc with id 91444447
Chrome 36.0.1985 (Linux): Executed 0 of 92 SUCCESS (0 secs / 0 secs)
Chrome 36.0.1985 (Linux): Executed 1 of 92 SUCCESS (0 secs / 0.065 secs)
[...]
Chrome 36.0.1985 (Linux): Executed 91 of 92 SUCCESS (0 secs / 0.24 secs)
Chrome 36.0.1985 (Linux): Executed 92 of 92 SUCCESS (0 secs / 0.241 secs)
Chrome 36.0.1985 (Linux): Executed 92 of 92 SUCCESS (0.274 secs / 0.241 secs)
Chrome 36.0.1985 (Linux): Executed 93 of 92 SUCCESS (0.274 secs / 0.258 secs)
[...]
Chrome 36.0.1985 (Linux): Executed 183 of 92 SUCCESS (0.274 secs / 0.412 secs)
Chrome 36.0.1985 (Linux): Executed 184 of 92 SUCCESS (0.274 secs / 0.413 secs)

INFO [Iceweasel 30.0.0 (Linux)]: Connected on socket 4DISHs7012QeIwhEW9Hd with id 93232241

Chrome 36.0.1985 (Linux): Executed 184 of 92 SUCCESS (0.274 secs / 0.413 secs)
Iceweasel 30.0.0 (Linux): Executed 0 of 92 SUCCESS (0 secs / 0 secs)
Chrome 36.0.1985 (Linux): Executed 184 of 92 SUCCESS (0.274 secs / 0.413 secs)
Iceweasel 30.0.0 (Linux): Executed 1 of 92 SUCCESS (0 secs / 0.003 secs)
[...]
Iceweasel 30.0.0 (Linux): Executed 91 of 92 SUCCESS (0 secs / 0.201 secs)
Chrome 36.0.1985 (Linux): Executed 184 of 92 SUCCESS (0.274 secs / 0.413 secs)
Iceweasel 30.0.0 (Linux): Executed 92 of 92 SUCCESS (0 secs / 0.202 secs)
Chrome 36.0.1985 (Linux): Executed 184 of 92 SUCCESS (0.274 secs / 0.413 secs)
Iceweasel 30.0.0 (Linux): Executed 92 of 92 SUCCESS (0.303 secs / 0.202 secs)
TOTAL: 276 SUCCESS
```

Configuration:

```
module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({

    basePath : 'www',

    frameworks : [ 'jasmine' ],

    files : [ 'js/*' ],

    exclude : [ 'spec/lib/*.js' ],

    reporters : [ 'progress', 'junit', 'html', 'coverage' ],

    coverageReporter : {
      type : 'html',
      dir : 'coverage/'
    },

    preprocessors : {
      'js/*.js' : 'coverage',
    },

    junitReporter : {
      outputFile : 'test-results.xml'
    },

    colors : true,

    logLevel : config.LOG_INFO,

    autoWatch : true,

    browsers : [ 'Firefox', 'Chrome' ],

    captureTimeout : 20000,

    reportSlowerThan : 500,

    plugins : [ 'karma-jasmine', 'karma-coverage', 'karma-html-reporter', 'karma-chrome-launcher', 'karma-junit-reporter', 'karma-phantomjs-launcher', 'karma-firefox-launcher' ]

  });
};
```

Comment: How does your config-file look like?

Comment: @seven-ply http://paste.debian.net/110248/

Comment: Do you have an existing tab on Chrome when you launch the test? Sometimes I've got the same issue with Safari and usually it's this.

Comment: @MarcoCI: No, it is a headless server with a fresh X server started for those tests. No chrome instance was running when the test started.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? I have the same issue.

Comment: Not knowingly, but I don't work on this project anymore. I guess it still happens, though.

Answer (score 9):

I know this is an old question but for me the problems was with `reporters` setting in karma config file.

I had:
`reporters: ['progress', 'dots', 'junit']`

Running **progress** with **dots** caused the tests running twice (or rather showing it run twice).

So the solution was to leave out one of those reporters.

Comment: same here, my issue was with the reporters as well. +1

Comment: Does not apply in my case there's only the "dots" reporter. (Karma 4.0.0, Chrome-Launcher 2.2.0, specs included, sources not included, both type "module"). And except the cause changed while the symptom remained, I doubt reporters would change the fact that the scripts get loaded twice (confirmed via `console.log()`).

Comment: @try-catch-finally That's a different issue then. Did you try other answers?

Answer (score 5):

You might have your karma config wrong.  It should know where your test files are but not include them:

```
files : ['js/*']
```

might need to change to:

```
files : ['js/*.js',
         { pattern: 'tests/*.js', included: false }]
```

(This expects your source files to be under `./js/` and your tests to be under `./tests/`

(I got this from [https://medium.com/@SchizoDuckie/so-your-karma-tests-run-twice-this-is-what-you-need-to-do-be74ce9f257e#.m3ci0m5vb] and it worked for me)

Answer (score 2):

This happened to me simply because I had another Chrome tab open and pointing to the Karma server.

Answer (score 0):

For me Chrome was runing script twice in 50% cases because I didn't had favicon.ico. Took me a day to find it out :)
Does your icon for the page appears in the Chrome browser?
If not, Chrome looking for favicon.ico, and if your site return 404 page with same php code, chrome will do it twice.

```
<link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" sizes="32x32" type="image/png" />
```

Comment: I don't use a webserver, so there is no 404 code. And as far as I know, this icon is optional.

Answer (score 0):

You must be including jasmine's boot.js which runs its own set of test cases along with karma test cases

Answer (score 0):

This was happening to me because I had not specified the browser in my Karma Run/Debug configuration.
Specify that under "Browsers to start" (as shown below).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For me, it happened because I specified multiple browsers in the `browsers` section of `karma.conf.js`

```
browsers: ['Chrome' , 'ChromeHeadless', 'ChromeHeadlessCI'],
```